Regions bounds (created from a Path) are not as expected
I need to check if a point lies inside of a Path describing a 2d shape.
As Path object doesn't have contains function, but Region does and we can construct a Region out of a Path I tried it.
But the Region doesn't seem to have my expected bounds, so I wrote a small test to play around.
fun boundsTest() {
    val clipRegion = Region(0, 0, 100, 100)
    val pathRectF = RectF()

    // Create a path describing a triangle
    val path = Path()
    path.moveTo(0F,0F)
    path.lineTo(5f, 5f)
    path.lineTo(5f, 0f)
    path.lineTo(0f, 0f)
    path.close()

    // Compute the exact bounds of the path
    path.computeBounds(pathRectF, true)
    val pathBoundingBox = pathRectF.toRect()
    Log.i("MyLog", "boundsTest: pathBoundingBox: $pathBoundingBox")

    // Create a region from the bounding box of the path
    val pathBoundingRegion = Region(pathBoundingBox)
    Log.i("MyLog", "boundsTest: pathBoundingBoxRegion: $pathBoundingRegion")
    Log.i("MyLog", "boundsTest: pathBoundingBoxRegion.bounds: ${pathBoundingRegion.bounds}")
    pathBoundingRegion.setPath(path, clipRegion)

    val bounds = pathBoundingRegion.bounds
    Log.i("MyLog", "boundsTest: $bounds")
    assertTrue { bounds.left == 0 }
}`

You see I have Path describing a simple triangle which should result in a pathBoundingBox of (0, 0, 5, 5) having 5 in width and height.
Then I create a Region from it and get the bounds of the Region so verify it still has the same bounding box, but logs look like this.
boundsTest: pathBoundingBox: Rect(0, 0 - 5, 5)
boundsTest: pathBoundingBoxRegion: SkRegion((0,0,5,5))
boundsTest: pathBoundingBoxRegion.bounds: Rect(0, 0 - 5, 5)
boundsTest: Rect(1, 0 - 5, 4)
As you can see, everything looks fine, but the last log seems to be odd. Left is 1 instead of 0 and bottom is 4 instead of 5, leading to a width and height of 4 instead of 5.
I tried to play around with some stuff like the clipRegion
val clipRegion = Region(-1, -1, 100, 100)
val clipRegion = Region(0, 0, Int.MAX_VALUE - 1, Int.MAX_VALUE - 1)
or the Path (negative y values or excluding initial moveTo() and close()
or different ways to set the path
pathBoundingRegion.setPath(path, Region(pathBoundingBox.left, pathBoundingBox.top, pathBoundingBox.right, pathBoundingBox.bottom))
or
pathBoundingRegion.setPath(path, Region(pathRectF.left.toInt(), pathRectF.top.toInt(), pathRectF.right.toInt(), pathRectF.bottom.toInt()))
But nothing seems to work.
I know there are other ways for my initial problem and as I am also grateful for every alternative approach you might have, I would highly appreciate if someone could help me solve this approach, as I feel I am missing something.
